# OCX library with C# (ActiveX library)

Tags: c#, wpf, activex, ocx

whats the simplest way to make ocx library working in c#? (I'm using wpf project) I tried to use aximp, but when creating Ax[libname]Lib.Ax[libname] object, calling getocx() returns null.

EDIT: I should add, that this lib is for communicating with some specific driver

Comment: If you use C#/WPF, why don't you use Xbap or silverlight?

Comment: @jdv: Silverlight doesn't make WPF obsolete...

Comment: @Reed: of course not. But it would be my #1 choice if I need to run WPF in a browser. ActiveX controls are IE only, and increasingly harder to deploy because of tightened security.

Comment: @jdv: ActiveX controls (ocx) are not necessarily for in-browser usage.  They were also used quite commonly for desktop applications, and usable in VB6, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found solution :) After creating object, it's necessary to call method .CreateControl()

Comment: If you are calling CreateControl yourself then there's no point in using aximp.exe.  That creates a control you can put on a form.  In which case calling CreateControl is unnecessary.

Comment: For now it's only way, I tried to add this to toolbox but it was impossible for me to do